# Why does Text content occupy all the parent element space？

Tags: react-native

react-native -v:  0.61.5

Why does Text content occupy all the parent element space?

Here is my demo. iOS devices is different from that on the Web.

https://snack.expo.io/@hejingdong/centered-image-text-container

Here is iOS screenshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNs0B.jpg)

Here is Web screenshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsZTL.png)

Here is my design.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FJVu.png)

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

The content of the text occupies all the parent content because you define flex: 1, and the parent has no size, so it is growing with his children, you can use maxWidth in the text container, so the images will not be pushed out of a View.
Mobile has different behaviors, isnt only IOS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my Text can't be fixed in width, so I calculated the parent component and set the maxWidth of the Text, so I can meet my design.

Answer (score 0):

Your text has no width specified so it was taking the full width of your parent container. Add width to your text

```
<Text style={[styles.container, {width : '80%'}]} numberOfLines={1}>asdasfsdfpasoidufpiasupdfoiaupsdiufaa</Text>
```

Or you can either increase your `numberOfLines` if the text is too large.